# Cannot retrieve first elements of hash containing temp files

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a hash made of files that I get from a multipart file (that i get through dropzone.js):

```
uploaded_pics = params[:file]
```

Then i determine the numer of allowed pics that the user can upload represented by `availableimages` which is an integer.

Lastly i try to get the first allowed elements of hash with the following bits by retrieving the first `availableimages` of hash `uploaded_pics`:

```
 selectedpics = p Hash[uploaded_pics.sort_by { |k,v| -v }[0..availableimages]]
 selectedpics = p uploaded_pics.first(availableimages).to_h
 selectedpics = Hash[uploaded_pics.to_a[1..availableimages]]
 selectedpics = uploaded_pics.keys.sort[1..availableimages].each { |key| puts "#{key} #{hash[key]}" }
 selectedpics = uploaded_pics.first(5)
```

But all fail.

I think some of these attempts try to convert the hash into an array; which is not possible as the hash elements are not simple integers but files. Some fail for other reasons (conversions to_a etc....)

I will do the test on the client side, but I would like to do the test on the controller side too! then I need a method to pick only the n first elements of a hash, and keep the pairs untouched ...

EDIT

Not sure if this helps, but here is the hash returned by `params:[file]` when i try to upload two random file :

```
    <ActionController::Parameters 
{"0"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x13ca7678 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:C:/Users/Maxence/AppData/Local/Temp/RackMultipart20170616-8024-ks1b8u.jpg>, @original_filename="4.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file[0]\"; filename=\"4.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, 
"1"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x13ca7648 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:C:/Users/Maxence/AppData/Local/Temp/RackMultipart20170616-8024-1ut7trw.jpg>, @original_filename="4.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file[1]\"; filename=\"4.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">} permitted: false>
```

Comment: i couldn't understand your question. secondly is it possible to provide code etc which we can replicate?

Comment: well let's say I have a hash (made of pairs of which value is a file). I want to grab the first n elements of this hash. `params[:file]` is actually a hash

Comment: have you removed the puts from the equation like @Md. said below - that will stop selectedpics from equalling nil

Comment: oh ok. didnt know p stans for put. trying this now.

Comment: Sergio has answered it ! thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work.

```
n_keys = uploaded_pics.keys.first(availableimages)
filtered_pics = uploaded_pics.slice(*n_keys)
```

Comment: ...where `Hash#slice` is a Rails method, not available in Ruby.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: the boundaries are so blurry!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `p` while assigning to a variable,

```
selectedpics = Hash[uploaded_pics.sort_by { |k,v| -v }[0..availableimages]]
selectedpics = uploaded_pics.first(availableimages).to_h
selectedpics = Hash[uploaded_pics.to_a[1..availableimages]]
selectedpics = uploaded_pics.keys.sort[1..availableimages].each { |key| puts "#{key} #{hash[key]}" }
selectedpics = uploaded_pics.first(5)
```

Comment: `p` doesn't cause any problems here (it returns its argument)

Comment: I see, actually this should be a comment rather than an answer..I don't know what made me post it here..